# How to hide the dates from next month in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on jQuery Full Calendar Plugin

I am able to show the calendar but it is showing the dates of next month, How can I hide them,

For more clarification please see the attached file :

[image]

Comment: Do you mean this? http://fullcalendar.io/ Is there no support on that page?

Comment: There is no such option, unfortunately. You can [create your own view](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) to display only the days you want but that is more advanced and the documentation is minimal.